# If each connected component of a submanifold of Euclidean space embeds does the entire manifold embed?

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have been working on a problem where I want to prove an injective immersion $f$ from a submanifold $M \subset R^n$ (actually, a level set) to $R^k,\; k \geq \dim M$ is a topological embedding. If I knew $M$ was connected I could do it (I believe) and so I have been twisting myself into a pretzel trying to come up with a proof. Then I thought: **Question**: Does $M$ have to be connected? What if I could show that $f$ restricted to each connected component of $M$ was a topological embedding to its image? Would that suffice to show that the image of $M$ is an embedded submanifold of $R^k$?

Since immersions are inherently local and topological embeddings don't seem to depend on connectivity, I can't immediately see why that wouldn't be true.

Any pointers towards a way of proving/disproving this would be appreciated.

**Edit** To correct inequality.

**Edit** I see where the title of my post is more general than I intended. I have changed the title to accurately reflect the actual question I'm asking. Apologies for perhaps misleading some.

**Edit** Ben Steffan pointed out that the way I posed the question might be too general, hence misleading. Let me put it this way:

**Revised Question** I want to prove that the image of a submanifold $M \subset R^n$ of dimension $m$ by a function $f: M \rightarrow R^k$ ($k \geq m$) is an embedded submanifold. I already know that $f$ is an injective immersion and that $f$ restricted to each connected component of $M$ is a topological embedding. Can I conclude that $f(M)$ is an embedded submanifold of $R^k$? **Note**: In my specific case $f$ is actually the projection of $M$ onto a subset of coordinates, but I don't think that matters here.

Comment: Try to find a counter example when $n=2$. At the same time, if each component embeds in $R^n$, so does the entire manifold.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Thanks, but I am not quite understanding (my fault). Are you guiding me to find a counter example, for $n=2$, to the title of my post but that in general, if each connected component of $M$ embeds in $R^k$ then $M$ does as well?

Comment: Are you sure you mean $k < \dim M$? In that case the answer to your question is trivially true since there are no immersions $M \to \mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: @Ben Steffan. Oops, I see where I got that, no, $m \leq k$. I'll edit the question. Thanks much.

Comment: Yes, if $M$ is a manifold with countably many components (which is implied by the 2nd countability condition) and each component embeds in $R^k$ then the manifold admits an embedding in $R^k$. It is a very good exercise to do.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Understood. I think Ben Steffan may have "let the cat out of the bag" but this is stuff I need to understand (that's the wannabe mathematician in me talking). Thanks much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Even if the restrictions of $f$ to the components of $M$ are already embeddings, $f$ need not be: I submit this poorly drawn sketch derived from Example 4.19 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds as a counterexample: [image: sketch of two embeddings from disjoint open intervals into the plane with combined image homeomorphic to the wedge sum of three copies of the circle]
The maps taking the blue interval $(0, 2)$ to the blue curve above and the red interval $(-2, 0)$ to the red curve below can both be chosen embeddings (I'll leave coming up with parametrizations and verifying this to you as an exercise :), but it is not an embedding: its image is compact while its domain is not.

Comment: 2Ben Steffan Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I appreciate the work. I'll need to study it, in pieces, but I have a question right off the bat, about your first sentence. Lee's 4.19 is a classic example of an immersed but not embedded submanifold, but the map $\beta$ of that example (AFAIK) is not a topological embedding. Part of my question included $f$ being a topological embedding as well. So, quite apart from the question of whether $M$ is connected or not, why wouldn't the image of my $f$ be an embedded submanifold?

Comment: @HerbF1978 Perhaps I misread your question, but the first part is to address "I have been working on a problem where I want to prove an injective immersion [...] is a topological embedding. If I knew $M$ was connected I could do it (I believe)". The part after then addresses the actual question. I'll reword things to (hopefully) be a bit clearer.

Comment: First, please see my comment above, it probably didn't get to you. Second, I do understand your "hand drawn" example, quite well explained and instructive. I'll have to study your last point, it unfortunately won't help in the particular applied case I'm dealing with but I like theoretical math much more than applied. :) Frankly, I "know" the manifold I'm dealing with is connected, I just am having a heck of a time proving it. I was hoping to sidestep the problem, but no joy. Thanks again (to you and Moishe Kohan).

Comment: Oh, I see, no, what I meant is that I want to prove that $f$ is a topological embedding of $M$ into $R^k$ but right now all I can do is prove that $f$ restricted to each connected component of $M$ is a topological embedding. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @HerbF1978 I see. Your question does read to be quite a bit more general to me, and I think I'm not alone (judging from Moishe Koshan's comments) in this :) I'll edit my answer down to be a better fit.

Comment: Well, then, I'll edit it. Still, you've pointed out what I thought might be true is not, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

For the revised question: Let $M= (-2,0)\cup (0,1)$ embedded in the $x$-axis in ${\mathbb R}^2$. Define a map $f: M\to {\mathbb R}^2$ by:

1. $f$ restricted to $(0,1)$ is the identity map.
2. $f$ restricted to $(-2,0)$ is the composition of the rotation by $\pi/2$ (counterclockwise) around the origin, followed by the translation by the vector $[0, 1]$.

I will leave it to you to check that $f$ is an embedding when restricted to both components of $M$, but the image of $f$ is not a topological manifold, hence, is not a submanifold of ${\mathbb R}^2$.

Now, to the question in the title.

Lemma. Suppose that $M$ is a (2nd countable) manifold such that each component of $M$ embeds in ${\mathbb R}^k$. Then $M$ admits an embedding in  ${\mathbb R}^k$. (This works in both category of topological manifolds and differentiable manifolds.)

Proof. Let $M_j, j\in J$, denote the connected components of $M$, where $J$ is countable. The key is that each component $M_j$ is both open and closed in $M$. Suppose that for each $j\in J$ there exists an embedding $f_j: M_j\to  {\mathbb R}^k$. Now, use the fact that
${\mathbb R}^k$ contains a disjoint union of open balls $B_j, j\in J$ (since $J$ is countable) and that each $B_j$  is diffeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^k$. qed

Comment: Excellent, thank you for providing this. I realize the title of my post was not accurate, I usually worry about the content but didn't stop to consider that contributors initially can only go by the title. I'll work on your answer and add it to my "memory bank", useful should a similar situation arise in the future.